altering and/or mixing orbitals for GVB-PP
I'm trying to use Gaussian 16 C.01 to run a minimal perfect-pairing generalized valence bond (GVB-PP) calculation on Li2. The online user guide tells me to do a preliminary run with Guess=(Local,Only) to determine orbital alteration requirements. So I did as told, and g16 finished this first run without errors.  Can someone tell me what information I need from the log file for altering the orbitals in order to do the main GVB run? I've pasted my input file below. Just removing ,Only leads to a crash with the error message "attempt to read past end of file".
%chk=main-gvb
%mem=2GB
%nprocshared=4
#P GVB(1)/STO-3G Guess=(Local,Only) Units(Ang,Deg)

Li2 minimal

0,1
Li    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Li    0.000000    0.000000    2.673000


I tried running the example from the user guide (the one with Guess=(Local,LowSym,Alter)) which also crashed with the same error message. So it looks like g16 was expecting something other than the orbital numbers to be switched...
Thanks in advance for any help.

Caveat: I have no experience with GVB-PP calculations, but I can at least point you in the right direction for your input errors.
The "attempt to read past end of file" error occurs because GVB is one of those funny Gaussian keywords that requires additional input at the end of the input file. In this case, it is the "number of orbitals in each GVB pair", which is specified as a single line, one white-spaced separated integer per pair. In your calculation, you are calculating only a single GVB pair, so the correct input would be:
%chk=main-gvb
%mem=2GB
%nprocshared=4
#P GVB(1)/STO-3G Guess=(Local) Units(Ang,Deg)

Li2 minimal

0,1
Li    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Li    0.000000    0.000000    2.673000

2

Note the 2 on a separate line. This is assuming you wanted 2 natural orbitals per pair. As another example, if you wanted to do GVB(3), your input might look like this:
%chk=main-gvb
%mem=2GB
%nprocshared=4
#P GVB(3)/STO-3G Guess=(Local) Units(Ang,Deg)

Li2 minimal

0,1
Li    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Li    0.000000    0.000000    2.673000

2 2 2

And so on. In both these examples, we are not making any changes to the orbital occupations, which the manual seems to suggest you should be doing.
Changing orbital assignments
The Gaussian manual includes some examples that give a few hints on how you might go about doing this:
# GVB(3)/6-31G(d) Pop=Full Guess=(Local,LowSym,Alter)

GVB(3) on CH2

molecule specification

1 4 0 2 3 9                !Guess=LowSym input
2,3                        !Guess=Alter input

2 2 2                      !GVB input

All three of the Guess=LowSym, Guess=Alter, and GVB(3) keywords expect additional input lines, and these should be given at the end of the input file in the order indicated. Note that the text after the ! is just a comment, and shouldn't be included (eg, !Guess=LowSym input). In this example, based on the initial Guess=Only calculation (like you did), the author decided to make the following changes to the orbital assignment:

The symmetry of the orbitals has been deliberately lowered. The format for this line (1 4 0 2 3 9) is complicated, but in short both 0 and 9 are terminators. I interpret this as meaning irreps 1 and 4 should be combined, and irreps 2 and 3 should be combined. These irrep numbers (here 1, 4, 2 and 3) apparently "correspond to the order in which the representations are listed by Link 301 in the output file" (manual).  Note that unlike most other Gaussian input options, this line is not terminated by a blank line.
The occupation of orbitals 2 and 3 has been swapped. Orbital 2, which is nominally an occupied orbital, will instead be left empty while orbital 3 is populated instead. The example in the Gaussian manual doesn't include a terminating blank line, but I think this is a mistake.

I'm afraid I can't offer any help as to which orbitals you might want to swap, or which symmetry you need, hopefully the Gaussian example tells you want you need!

Exactly what I needed. Thanks @leeman !
